# CakePHP Custom route calling wrong action

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have the following code in `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/c/details/:id/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'cars'),
    array('pass' => array('id', 'slug'))
);
```

If I try to access `http://domain.com/c/details/123/abc`, it works. However, if I remove `abc` (ie the slug), CakePHP tries to access the action `123` (which is the id, not the action).

```
Error: The action 123 is not defined in controller CarsController
```

If I use `/c/details/:id/:slug/:action/*`, which was what I had before upgrading from 1.2 (yeah, pretty old) to 2.2.1 and it was working fine, CakePHP also tries to access action `123` whether I have a slug or not.

URLs without slugs always worked before upgrading CakePHP and with the code I have in the controller, if there was no slug in the URL, it would redirect to the right URL.

**Edit:** I just checked and it seems that when I don't provide with a slug, the whole thing is shifted. `c` is ignored, `details` becomes the controller and `123`becomes the action.

```
[request] => CakeRequest Object
    (
        [params] => Array
            (
                [plugin] => 
                [controller] => details
                [action] => 123
                [named] => Array()
                [pass] => Array()
                [isAjax] => 
            )
```

When the correct would be, and which is what I get if I provide with a slug:

```
[request] => CakeRequest Object
    (
        [params] => Array
            (
                [plugin] => 
                [controller] => cars
                [action] => index
                [named] => Array()
                [pass] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 123
                        [1] => abc
                    )

                [id] => 123
                [slug] => abc
                [isAjax] => 
            )
```

Any idea what may be causing this issue now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need 2 routes if you want the slug to be optional (not sure). In any case, add the `action` key to each route as well.

```
Router::connect('/c/details/:id',
    array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'details'),
    array('pass' => array('id'))
);

Router::connect('/c/details/:id/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'details'),
    array('pass' => array('id', 'slug'))
);
```

Comment: It worked! Weird because with the old cake version a single route was enough. Thanks.